Machine Learning model dependent on one feature
I am training a model for crop yield prediction having a self-constructed dataset of 6 features and 2000 records.
However, the dataset is biased and I am not getting accurate results. I have tried different algorithms as well as some pre-processing but still lack accurate results.
Here is the correlation of features with the target variable (production(kg)):

Region: NaN
CropType: NaN
Year: -0.019087
FieldArea(acres): 0.925150
Temperature(dc): 0.020016
WaterAvailablity(m3): -0.049801
SoilType: 0.028538
Name: production(kg), dtype: float64

Please suggest some solution for this.

maybe you should ask on similar portals DataScience and CrossValidated

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Given that FieldArea has such a strong correlation on your output, have you considered re-parameterizing your prediction problem? You could create a new column, production divided by field area, and drop production and field area from your dataset. The new problem would be to predict production per field area instead of predicting production.

As the community bot mentioned in the comments, what specific problem would you like to highlight?

Is it the fact that only FieldArea has a strong correlation (but you expect the other variables to also have some degree of correlation)?
If so, you might want to check your raw data and make sure that the sensors were correct (since it was self-constructed, I'd assume you have custom sensors?)

If your original dataset was biased, perhaps you can try undersampling or oversampling (common method to handle data imbalance)

Since your "Region" and "CropType" displayed 'NaN', you might want to try one-hot encoding (or any other methods) to handle categorical variables and 'convert' them into numerical ones!


Hope this helps!
